# How to adjust where the end of line is in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, editor

In IntelliJ (just like in Eclipse) there is a thin grey vertical line in the code editor. I assume that just like in Eclipse, the line is showing where the "end of line" is supposed to be.

2 questions:
1) Where do you adjust how long a line is allowed to be in IntelliJ?
2) If not using the exact same property from #1, where do you adjust where the line is shown in the editor?

Thanks!

Comment: Ok, I just figured it out:

Go to IDE Settings. The very first category on the right is Code Style->General->Right Margin (columns). Change the value there and it changes where the line is supposed to wrap as well as where the grey thin line appears.

Comment: FYI, you can answer your own question - then others will know to look for it as the accepted answer

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Go to **Settings → Editor → Code Style → Right Margin (columns)**.

Comment: I believe this answer is out-of-date. The correct approach is as explained by @Benoit

Answer (score 10):

In IntelliJ 2019-2023 and newer versions, go to **Settings** → **Editor** → **Code Style**. Under the tab **General**, there are 2 useful settings regarding end-of-line:

- **Hard wrap at**, where you can define the text line maximum length.
- **Visual guide**, where you can add additional guides (add one or more grey vertical line).

[image: as of 2023]

Answer (score 4):

For IntelliJ 14 users:

In IDE Settings, Editor → General → Appearance, uncheck show right margin.

Answer (score 2):

While being able to configure the setting I didn't get expected result from it. Later figured out that I didn't use monospaced font in the editor which made the margin setting behave odd. Hope that helps to those looking to solve this particular problem.