# How do I set the line length vertical line on the right in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

In the IntelliJ, I set the line length vertical line on the right.

But, for some reason, the vertical line is on the 90, even though I set the word wrap at 120.

How do I change the vertical line to be on 120?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to adjust where the end of line is in IntelliJ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19407598/how-to-adjust-where-the-end-of-line-is-in-intellij)

Comment: Check "Hard wrap at" and "Visual guide" settings for the language you are using (e.g. Preferences | Editor | Code Style | Java | Wrapping and Braces | Hard wrap at)